Screen color control (temperature)
Does anyone know if there is an application where I can control the screen color? Specifically for blue light. In Cinnamon there is this applet, but I wanted something for Ubuntu. Redshift is not very good, as it is not visual, not great for new users.I don't want those things that automatically change color according to the sun. I just want to be able to lower the blue light or change the screen temperature. Honestly, I don't know why there isn't a native setting for this. And I'm not talking about the night light.


gsettings list-recursivley |grep bright

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you try checking the options under Settings -> Devices -> Color??
